# localhost:8080/abc/swagger-ui/index.html showing 404 not found after migrating from swagger2 to openApi3

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, swagger-ui, springdoc-openapi-ui

Migrated to openApi3 SpringBoot project. But I'm not able to get swagger ui page while /v3/api-docs/ url working. But swagger url showing 404 not found. I'm also able to access /v3/api-docs/swagger-config/.

I'm using springdoc-openapi-ui dependency having version 1.6.11. I tried every possible way. For one time UI was displaying somehow but after restarting server it disappears. FYI, I've implemented SwaggerConfig.java and ConfigWebSecurity.java for ignoring url from spring security.In short i have implemented all those things which is mentioned for migration from swagger to openApi3 in official documentation.
FYI -
I have migrated 2 other applications by following same process. But for this app I'm facing this issue.
Thank in advance

Comment: Well it will be good if you put you code and depedencies and logs but in your application.properties you can customize the acces url of swagger3 by : `spring.swagger-ui.path=/swagger/index.html` and also  `spring.api-docs=what you want`

Answer (score 0):

what url are you trying for ui page ?
Try using `localhost:YourPort/swagger-ui.html` .